# How to improve performance in three.js application

Tags: performance, three.js

I wrote an application  with more than thousands of spheres on specific coordinates with specific colors and the same number of cylinders. With larger amount of atoms(spheres) and bonds(cylinders) my application has lower and lower performance. I need to optimize my code in three.js to improve performance. First I tried to decrease number of segments on  spheres and cylinder but it was little.

How can I improve performance of my application?

Are there many ways how to reach this goal?

Comment: This is kind of impossible question to give a definite answer to. However some things you can try are using BufferGeometry as well as merging your geometries. If it is possible to get a look you want by using particles instead of meshes, you could possibly gain huge improvements.

Comment: I only need some tips on how to achieve increased performance.Thank you for your tips